# Conversion of Enhanced Meta File (EMF) to Printer Command Language(PCL5) using C#

Tags: c#, byte, printer-control-language

In WMF Aldus header there is a property named "Inch"  to get  “Number of metafile units per inch”.

Since similar property is missing in EMF, Could you please let me know how can I calculate the equivalent of the above one in EMF?

My requirement is to convert an EMF file to PCL (help using any other raster format will as do)

Could you please enlighten me with any sample code or helpful links.

Thanks in Advance